# How to remove html tag and wrap it with another tag

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to remove the some elements under a table cell.

my html is like

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
     <span>first text</span>
     <span>second text</span>
     <span>third text</span>
  </td>
   <td>
     <span>1st text</span>
     <span>2nd text</span>
     <span>3rd text</span>
   </td>
</tr>
…more
```

I want my html become

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
     <span>first text second text third text</span>
  </td>
   <td>
     <span>1st text 2nd text 3rd text</span>
   </td>
</tr>
…more
```

I have tried.

```
$('table td span').contents().unwrap().wrap('<span></span>');
```

but I got the same results as my original one.

Are there anyways to do this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you should be able to do something like .text() and then wrap that in a span. (then you should do $('table td') instead)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Need to iterate each `td` and use `wrapAll` instead of `wrap`:

```
$('table td').each(function() {
    $(this).find('span').contents().unwrap().wrapAll('<span></span>');
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gNMCh/

Comment: The only change I had to that was `$(this).find('span').append(' ')` so that the text had a space between after the `<span>`s were removed.